# MYOB database Schema

Tags: odbc, myob

i want to import data from MYOB through odbc connection
i have successfully created the odbc connection and select queries are working fine.
i want to have a look at MYOB database schema so that i can write queries to retrieve data.
how can i get the schema of the MYOB database?
i made this odbc connection in server explorer, the connection has been succeeded but the server explorer cant show me the list of tables/views in the connection.
kindly help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

The following links to the developer resource kit. This kit contains a full shcema description.

http://myobaustralia.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/myobaustralia.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=30548

If the above link expires try this one:

http://myob.com.au/partners/become-a-partner/developers-1258090671897

Answer (score 0):

There are documentations found in the installation folder of the ODBC drivers.

usually found c:\MYOBODBC[xyz]\doc or help.

BTW, you need to have a developer key to enable write access to the MYOB database.

Hope this helps.